# What information will dig leak to an attacker? 

Tags: privacy, tools

What information will the `axfr` and `ixfr` commands in DIG provide to an attacker?

Comment: Interesting question. Perhaps, there should be a tag for "interview-questions" in this QnA.

Comment: btw... nice handle, reminds me of me :D

Comment: I have tried to fix the question. It wasn't a good security question previously, and I nearly closed as off topic.

Comment: @RoryAlsop this user is simply copy-pasting questions from certification exams. This one is question 2 from [this exam](http://exam.test4actual.com/EC0-479.pdf)

Comment: @tylerl - yes they have been warned and given a temporary suspension. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AXFR is the traditional way of zone transferring - you just completely copy the dns records from one zone to the other - an attacker will have a complete list of resources in the organizations and if you save some more information on those servers on your nameserver it will be included

IXFR on the other hand helps sysadmins in replicating an already given zone that was doing a complete AXFR in the past and need to be updated to the latest record revision on the nameserver, without the hassle and band-choking of a complete copy of records.
in IXFR you can select the revision that you have and the server will provide you with the updated data since your revision, to an attacker is the same as before - just less information.

Answer (score 0):

She wants to download the zone and discover the list of the machines with ip numbers she can access. This way, I just download the zone, and all the server names and it's ip numbers are revealed, so I look upon systems to which I can have access and I can try my login / password.

Easy way to accomplish this:

`host -a -l example.com`